# Sub to check a size in a textbox, vb

Tags: vb.net, subroutine

I am working on checking a specific bootsize entered in a text box in vb. We have to use a sub routine to check the size then call the routine after the button click. When I click the button no matter what the value it returns false even if the correct size is entered. Here is the code for the sub routine and button click.

```
Dim check As Boolean
Dim b As Boolean
Sub salomonsize(ByVal a As Integer, ByRef check As Boolean)
    If a = 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11 Or 12 Then
        b = True
    Else
        b = False
    End If
End Sub
 Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
 Call salomonsize(txtSalomonSize.Text, check)
    If check = False Then
        MsgBox("Wrong size")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things that could improve with your routine. First of all, the comparison should be:

```
If a = 6 Or a = 7 Or a = 8 Or a = 9 Or a = 10 Or a = 11 Or a = 12 Then
```

The way you were doing it before `If a = 6 or 7 or 8 ...` doesn't work, because any unsigned integer will always evaluate to true. As a result, your code was always getting `b = true`. The reason you were getting always false was because Visual Basic initializes Booleans to false by default, and you never assign anything to `check`, therefore `check = false`.

On the other hand, I would create a function instead of passing a value by reference. A function would make all of the necessary calculations, and return a value. The complete code looks as follow:

```
Function salomonsize(ByVal a As Integer) As Boolean
    If a = 6 Or a = 7 Or a = 8 Or a = 9 Or a = 10 Or a = 11 Or a = 12 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim check = salomonsize(txtSalomonSize.Text)
    If check = False Then
        MsgBox("Wrong size")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The way you were doing it, you were assigning `b = true` and `b = false`. I believe you meant to assign `check` to be equal true or false instead, since it is the value you later check.

Edit: An even better way to do this and avoid so many comparisons would be using an array:

```
Function salomonsize(ByVal a As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim ValidNumbers As Integer() = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
    If ValidNumbers.Contains(a) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

As you can see, if you need to add any more numbers, you simply add them to the array. You could even read them from a file if needed. Then using the `.Contains` function to compare your value. You could even simply do `Return ValidNumbers.Contains(a)` and avoid the If/Else entirely:

```
Function salomonsize(ByVal a As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim ValidNumbers As Integer() = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
    return ValidNumbers.Contains(a)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the fast input! SO helpful as I have been playing around with this for quite some time. If I had a higher reputation I would up vote, but nice to see such helpful people on here as I am new to stack. Thanks again!

Comment: @DodgerT Glad that it helped.